# Linux server 18.04 GUI keeps crashing/freezing

Tags: server, xubuntu, lubuntu, gui

I dug up an old 2core 4gb ram PC and installed linux server on it. Server runs fine, but I wanted to install a GUI for it, if I sometimes would need it. However, it seems to freeze or crash constantly after 5-10 minutes of using, sometimes even before I got a chance to login. This happened on every GUI, not just ubuntu-desktop but with Lubuntu and Xubuntu.

The PC doesn't have dedicated GPU and I reckoned that the processor should be able to run a lightweight GUI, but could that be part of the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would start debugging freezes at the lowest level, which in this case is the pc hardware itself. [Memtest](https://www.memtest86.com/) is a good start to see if the memory is good and the cooling can take some load.

Next step would be to check for errors in /var/log/syslog.